# Tracking VideoJS with Google Tag Manager

Tags: analytics, video.js, google-tag-manager

I would like to track VideoJS using Google Tag Manager. Since I am fairly new to GTM I have no idea how to proceed. I have only done some basic stuff like tracking mailto links and PDF downloads using tutorials.

I found a project on Github called [videojs-ga](https://github.com/mickey/videojs-ga) which looks promising, now how would I correctly connect and set this up in GTM? Idealy we would end up tracking the play count and how long the video's get watched. There is no need to track multiple videos per page since there is only one video on a single page at any time.

Also if there is a better way to track VideoJS with GTM I am open to suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you make a fork from the code in that repository/ download the file from src  and make the changes locally. In line 104 where it says:

```
 sendbeacon = function(action, nonInteraction, value) {
      if (window.ga) {
        ga('send', 'event', {
          'eventCategory': eventCategory,
          'eventAction': action,
          'eventLabel': eventLabel,
          'eventValue': value,
          'nonInteraction': nonInteraction
        });
      } else if (window._gaq) {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', eventCategory, action, eventLabel, value, nonInteraction]);
      } else if (options.debug) {
        console.log("Google Analytics not detected");
      }
    };
```

you replace the stuff within the sendbeacton function object in the following way:

```
 sendbeacon = function(action, nonInteraction, value) {
     dataLayer.push(
          'eventCategory': eventCategory,
          'eventAction': action,
          'eventLabel': eventLabel,
          'event' : 'videojs'                    
     );
};
```

(make sure your dataLayer variable is declared somewhere before your GTM code). Create a script tag that links the modified script to our page.

Then create three variables of the "dataLayer" type which read their values from eventCategory, eventAction and eventLabel respectively. Set up a Google Analytics tag and configure it for event tracking, and pass in the variables to the respective fields. Create a trigger type custom event, event eq 'videojs' and use it to fire the GA event tracking tag.